# How to get an HTTP response where Content-Encoding: chunked so I can get chunk-extensions

Tags: c#, http, .net-4.0, chunked-encoding

As the title suggests, I need to be able to get the "raw" HTTP response when `Content-Encoding: chunked` so I can manually parse it and extract data I need from chunk-extensions in the response body. So far I've been using `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` to make my requests/handle responses, so I'm hoping to continue using the classes in the `System.Net.Http` namespace. Is there an easy way to do this (even if it means extending a class, maybe `HttpClientHandler`)? Or do I need to branch out and use some other classes (`System.Net.HttpWebRequest/Response`) or work further down the stack?

Thanks in advance,
Dan